# Form Collection and dynamic <li> values .Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

When a form is submitted I need to collect dynamically created text values.

currently they are contained like so...

```html
<ul style="visibility:visible" class="list">

  <li id="listelem">
    <input hidden="hidden" value="JohnDoe1" name="listelemtext" type="text">JohnDoe1<span style="color:red;vertical-align:bottom;" id="removeListElement"><i style="vertical-align:middle;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
  </li>
  <li id="listelem">
    <input hidden="hidden" value="JohnDoe1234" name="listelemtext" type="text">JohnDoe1234<span style="color:red;vertical-align:bottom;" id="removeListElement"><i style="vertical-align:middle;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When the form is collected I do

```
string[] usernames = Request.Form.GetValues("listelemtext");
```

I also try

```
string[] usernames = collection.GetValues("listelemtext");
```

Basically I want to store a list of the names a client adds, but I can't seem to catch them in the Request/ Form Collection on post... can anyone notice what I am doing wrong?

---

UPDATE:

```js
    $('#addUser').on('click', function (e) {
            var val = $('#in').val();
            //iterate and make sure no duplicates
            
            if (val != "") {
                $('ul.list').append('<li id="listelem" ><input hidden="hidden" value="'+val+'" name="listelemtext" type="text"/>' + val + '<span style="color:red;vertical-align:bottom;"  id="removeListElement"><i style="vertical-align:middle;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span></a></li>');
            }
          
            $(".results").on("click", "#removeListElement", function () {
                $(this).parent('li').remove();
            }); 
    })
```

Script Portion Above for adding Names.

Over in the Visual Studio 2015 debugger I find that the FormCollection and Request both contain "listelemtext" in the list of keys, but they are null, I am expecting a list of strings.

Comment: you need to give unique ids, name to your hidden fields. as far i know. if u want to access this try giving unique name or ids. you can access them in code behind this.elementname.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you validated that the content exists within the form before postback?  Do they exist in Request.Form["listelemtext"] as a comma delimited list? - Use the debugger or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to determine the dynamic content is in the form post.

The content you show should result in the content your expecting, but its hard to tell what is going on because you've left all the other parts out.

Dynamic Data? - show your script for how the elements are added

Comment: After you add a couple use the F12 tools to verify element name/value and that it is under the form tag that is triggering the postback.    The F12 tools will also show you the form content that is posted back, but Fiddler is allot nicer.

Comment: try [input type="hidden"],    --- not [hidden="hidden" type="text"]

Comment: your also have an extra closing [a] tab, but no open tag ---- use F12 to inspect the HTML after the content is added to the form

Comment: Yup Id's are listelemtext after added, changed the input attributes (Thanks!), and in Form Data as part of Postback (when viewed in F12 menu) It correctly displays 3 values as.. Listelemtext:JohnDoe1  Listelemtext: JohnDoe123 Listelemtext: JohnDoe12345

Comment: can you now access them in your original code.  var values = Request.Form.GetValues("listelemtext") ?

Comment: No, values is null, same goes for the FormCollection method